# Hide views to a particular row , column or cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

We have multiple workers on a project who need to update their progress in our spreadsheet on google docs , although google allows to protect named ranges from an edit , but how to ensure that certain users should not *view* a particular cell\column or row.
There is a hide feature already but it is not on per user basis.

In short we need a finer granularity on what a user can view, currently google allows view\edit at entire spreadsheet level, not individual cell\row level. Can google docs (scripts) be tweaked to accomplish this?

Are there any other free solutions to accomplish this apart from googledocs?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can prepare different sheets for different users and use [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user) on an [onOpen function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers).....then later on to collate all information you can use some app script to collate and view.....